# Editing an excel 2003 Macro, Deleting to Copying

Tags: excel, copy, worksheet

I am currently using this code to find and delete all rows with a certain criteria... How can I edit it to just move the rows to another worksheet instead of deleting them?

```
  Sub Delete_Rows()
      Dim selectedValue As Integer

      myNum = Application.InputBox("Input Value")
      Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, del As Range
      Set rng = Intersect(Range("'potlife'!J2:J1500"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
      For Each cell In rng
      If (cell.value) = myNum _
      Then
      If del Is Nothing Then
      Set del = cell
      Else: Set del = Union(del, cell)
      End If
      End If
      Next cell
      On Error Resume Next
      del.EntireRow.Delete
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I noticed is you defined `selectedValue` but then seemed to use `myNum`. You'll want to start having "Option Explicit" at the top of every module. This will force you to declare variables and give you a compile error when you don't declare `myNum`, for example. To automatically insert "Option Explicit" in every module, click Tools>Options>Editor>Require Variable Declaration.

The code below asssumes a worksheet named "copied rows" and will copy the rows to it. Note that it will always copy the rows to row 2, even if there is already something there:

```
Sub Copy_Rows()
Dim myNum As Long
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet, wsTarget As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, CellsToCopy As Range

Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("potlife")
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("copied rows")
myNum = Application.InputBox("Input Value")
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Intersect(wsSource.Range("J2:J1500"), wsSource.UsedRange)
On Error GoTo 0
If rng Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = myNum Then
        If CellsToCopy Is Nothing Then
            Set CellsToCopy = cell
        Else
            Set CellsToCopy = Union(CellsToCopy, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next cell
On Error Resume Next
CellsToCopy.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range("A2")
End Sub
```

Comment: yeah I didnt notice that... the code still worked for its purpose. But I would need the macro to just add the rows to a growing list. I figured out a workaround though that does not require the rows to be copied. Thanks for the reply. I'm sure the code you supplied will help others so I'll hit correct.